# windows 7 - some icons disappeared on start menu, desktop, programm and features

Tags: windows

some of my icons disappeared, for example the whole Microsoft office icons, they disappeared in the start menu, programm and features and also on the desktop.,

what i've tried is , to go to the folder of the exe, and pin it to the taskbar this will also show up the icon for unknown exe. changing icon doesnt work for the shortcuts, its disabled.

then i made a new shortcut and put it on the desktop that will show up the original icon. so i can recreate the start menu and the desktop, but still the icons are missed in programm and features.

i also tried to delete the icon cache db a 100 times but that doesnt work.

has anybody a solution?

does somebody know where the icon references are stored in the registry. i dont know where to start

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild the icon cache.

If that doesn't work look here for a quick and easy fix.
http://www.arcane.org/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-windows-7-start-menu-icons/